# Auto Increment Excel OleDb Connection Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, auto-increment

I want to Auto Increment the ID when I am adding new data to excel and this codes doesn't Auto Increment it's Only increment by 2 and i can't understand why please helpp thankssss

```
Dim Value As Integer
    cn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "C:\\Users\\Barbatos\\Desktop\\Book3.xlsx " + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
    cm = New OleDbCommand("SELECT MAX ([ID]) FROM [Sheet1$]", cn)
    cn.Open()
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Read()
        Value = dr(0)
    Else
    End If
    dr.Close()
    Dim str As String
    Dim empid As Integer
    Dim newNumber As Integer
    str = "SELECT MAX([ID]) AS MAXIMUM FROM [Sheet1$]"
    Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, cn)
    'Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader
    If dr.HasRows Then
        While dr.Read()
            If empid = IsDBNull(dr("MAXIMUM")) Then
                newNumber = CInt(Val(empid)) + 1
            End If
            If newNumber = 0 Then
                newNumber = 1
                empid = CStr(newNumber)
            ElseIf newNumber = 1 Then
                newNumber = newNumber + 1
                empid = CStr(newNumber)
            Else
                newNumber = newNumber + 1
                empid = CStr(newNumber)
            End If
        End While
    End If
    dr.Close()
    Me.Label2.Text = empid
```

Comment: If you're only trying to retrieve a single value then you should not be calling `ExecuteReader`.  The `ExecuteScalar` method exists specifically for the purpose of retrieving a single value.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that it would be supported with Excel but I would expect so, so you can probably also use `ISNULL` in your SQL so that it is guaranteed to return a number: `ISNULL(MAX(ID), 0)` will return 0 if there is no value in the `ID` column.  That way, there's no need for extra checks in your VB code.

Comment: Why are you concatenating `String` literals to make a connection string?  There's never any point concatenating two literals.  If you do concatenate anything though, use the concatenation operator (&) rather than the addition operator (+).  If you want to construct a connection string from variables, use `String.Format`, string interpolation or a connection string builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise my comments, I'd be doing this:

```
Dim nextId As Integer

Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Barbatos\\Desktop\\Book3.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"),
      command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT MAX([ID]) FROM [Sheet1$]", connection)
    connection.Open()

    Dim currentId = command.ExecuteScalar()

    nextId = If(currentId Is DBNull.Value, 1, CInt(currentId) + 1)
End Using
```

or, if it's supported, this:

```
Dim nextId As Integer

Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Barbatos\\Desktop\\Book3.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"),
      command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ISNULL(MAX([ID]), 0) FROM [Sheet1$]", connection)
    connection.Open()

    nextId = CInt(command.ExecuteScalar()) + 1
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

SOlVED

```
If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Read()
        If IsDBNull(dr("MAXIMUM")) Then
            empid = 1
        Else
            empid = CInt(dr("MAXIMUM")) + 1
        End If
    Else
        empid = 1
    End If
```

Comment: Using that `IsDBNull` function is not specifically wrong but I would generally suggest not using VB Runtime functions.  The data reader has its own `IsDBNull` method or you can compare directly to `DBNull.Value`.